# Keeping player score in multiple sports with Polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Firstly, this is for university so I cannot be given an answer, rather have it explained why my code does not work and be pointed in the right direction in regards to a solution. This must be considered learning and no more than that. I have also had to change the method names etc.

So I have a player who plays multiple sports; he may be both a `BaseballPlayer` and/or `FootballPlayer`, which are subclasses of `Player`.

`BaseballSquad` and `FootballSquad` are the actual teams and are subclasses of `TeamList`. `TeamList` has an arrayList `protected ArrayList<Player> team` which stores a team's players. Players are added to the ArrayList via the `TeamList` method:

```
public void addPlayer(Player player)
    {
        team.add(player);
    }
```

Each player class (either `Baseball` or `Football`) has its own points tally method, differing only in `points` and `goals`. For the purpose of the assignment, the player and his tally is accessed via a `toString()` method. These are printed via `TeamList` by using an `Iterator` of type `Player`.

Adding a player to multiple sports works; printing a list of a team's players works.

What does NOT work is printing the correct score tally. For example, if I have a `Baseball` team and I add a `Football player` to that team, then what is printed is the player's `goal` tally, not his `Baseball points`.

As far as I understand it during `runtime` the class type remains unchanged but what I need it to be able to, in a sense, change a player's class as I want a `Football` player to be recognised as a `Baseball` player if that's the sport he plays.

I feel that I have made a silly mistake somewhere as the rest of the code works. Either that or I have fluked it so far. Any help at all is appreciated and I apologise that I cannot show the whole code!

Comment: Not quite sure what you're expecting but... this is just a generalized description of your assignment. Without showing any code, or any errors, or expected vs actual output, I don't see how anyone can even begin to answer this.

Comment: *"... if I have a Baseball team and I add a Football player to that team"* - then your code should throw an exception!

Comment: I thought I explained it toward the end. I said that I cannot work out how to make one class behave like another class; that if I add a footballer to a baseball team then I want to increment his baseball tally, right? But even if I do that, it is his goal tally which is printed. So I am failing to access the correct information. Please read the last 4 paragraphs if you feel the rest is meaningless.

Comment: @StephenC is does not throw an exception. It allows is because I am adding is as type Player. Why should it throw an exception?

Comment: I think you might have gotten your idea backwards.  Consider, a `Player` can play one or more `Sport`s, a `Sport` may have many `Player`s, but is unlikely to have the same `Player` twice. So, there is a relationship.  Instead of adding `Player`s to a `Sport`, you should add a `Sport` to the `Player`.  For each `Sport` that the `Player` plays, they also have a `Score`. By adding the `Sport` to the `Player`, you can further associate the `Score` with the `Player` and the `Sport` in a meaningful manner (as the `Score` belongs to the `Player` for a given `Sport`).

Comment: *" ... but what I need it to be able to, in a sense, change a player's class as I want a Football player to be recognised as a Baseball player if that's the sport he plays"* - then separate the concepts of person and player into distinct classes, and relate 1 person to multiple players.

Comment: Now, there could be additional management associated with all this to make it easier to list `Player`s for a given support and/or you could query the `Player` for the `Score` of a given `Sport`, return `0` or some other value to indicate that they don't play it. But simply trying to associate the `Score` and `Player` in the `Sport` is probably going to cause you issues - but I'm just throwing ideas around - the point is, you need to identify the relationships between the various objects and how best they can be managed/maintained

Comment: To answer your first question, because a football team should not contain a baseball **player**.  (It could contain the football player aspect of a person who is also a baseball player!)

Comment: @StephenC so perhaps I could make a more generalised 'Player' with no initial sport association and like I think MadProgammer is getting at, add the generalised player to the team/sport?

Comment: @MadProgrammer is right.  You need to *model* the concepts that you need to represent and their relationships.  Have they taught you a modeling language / notation yet?  UML class diagrams?  ER diagrams?

Comment: Something like that.  There are various ways to model this, depending on what your actual requirements are.

Comment: @StephenC very little. I'm 3 months into my 1st year.

Comment: Well UML diagrams are pretty easy to understand.  In their simplest form, they just model classes + subclasses + relationships between classes.  Here's an overview:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram.  I suggest that you read that ... then try to draw some diagrams representing your problem on paper.  Try different alternatives until you find one that represents what you need to represent.

Comment: @StephenC thank you! I might have a look into that before I carry on editing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you try to accomplish is undoable in Java. Player's object has only one real class, you could of course cast it up or down on the polymorphic hierarchy but casting a FootballPlayer to BaseballPlayer will result with an error. The reason you can add a football player to the collection along with baseball players is that collections in Java are covariant (explained [here](https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance)).

The closest resolution I could suggest is to experiment with more complex class hierarchies as Java allows us to implement more than one interface at a time (in opposite the limit of extending only one class).

Hope I was helpful in a way that will allow you to complete the task on your own.

Answer (score 0):

> What does NOT work is printing the correct score tally. For example, if I have a Baseball team and I add a Football player to that team, then what is printed is the player's goal tally, not his Baseball points.

Okay, that doesn't make any sense, why would a `Football` player be associated with `Baseball`?  How would the program differentiate what `Score` it should be getting from the `Player` in this case and would it make any sense to do so?

If it doesn't make sense in the real world, it's unlikely to make sense in the virtual world either

> As far as I understand it during runtime the class type remains unchanged but what I need it to be able to, in a sense, change a player's class as I want a Football player to be recognised as a Baseball player if that's the sport he plays.

I would guess your assumption is right, in that `FootballPlayer` doesn't magically change to a `BaseballPlayer`.  `Baseball` should not allow you to add any other type of `Player` other then `BaseballPlayer`s.  The only way a `FootballPlayer` could play `Baseball` is if they were also a `BaseballPlayer`.

Now, in Java you can achieve this through the user of `interfaces`, so a player could play multiple sports, the problem you need to overcome, is how to get the `Player`'s score for a specific `Sport` - where should this information actually be maintained?  Does it belong to the `Sport` or the `Player`?

Let's take a step back and try and see the bigger picture.  From your description you have...

- A `Player`, who may play zero or more `Sport`s
- A `Sport`, which may have zero or more `Player`s (but probably won't have the same `Player` more then once).  A `Sport` is a container for a specific type of `Player` (ie `Baseball` is a container of `BaseballPlayer`s)
- A `Score`, which is associated to a `Player` AND a `Sport`. How you manage this is up to you, I'm going to suggest associating the `Score` with the `Player` directly.

So, the basic concept is:

- A `Sport` may contain zero or more (specific) `Player`s, but may only contain a single instance of any given `Player` (Fred can't play `Baseball` twice)
- A `Player` can play multiple `Sport`s (which can be achieved through the use of `interface`s), so Fred can play `Baseball` and `Football`
- A `Score` is associated with a `Player` for a given `Sport`

Since the baseline requirement seems to be that the `Sport` needs to be able to list the `Player`'s scores and (I'm assuming) it would be possible to list the `Player`'s scores for all the `Sport`s they play, it make sense to me to allow `Player` to manage the `Score`.

So, you might imagine a `Player` "might" look something like this...

```
public interface Player {
    // Bunch of other functionality...

    public List<Sport> getSports();
    public Map<Sport, Score> getScores();
    public Score getScore(Sport sport);
}
```

This means that when you want to list the `Score`s for all the `Player`s for a given `Sport`, `Sport` would loop through it's `List` of `Player`s and get the `Score` for itself, maybe something like this...

```
for (Player player : players) {
    Score score = player.getScore(this);
}
```

But if you want to know all the `Score`s/`Sport`s for a given `Player`, you could get that information directly from the `Player` themselves.

This is just a broad idea/concept which attempts to decouple some of the code and provide a broad baseline from which you can develop more complex relationships/data

Polymorphism doesn't change the base type of the object.  It simply allows the object to act/behave like a different type of object (confused yet).  That is, you could have a `Player` behave like a `BaseballPlayer` AND a `FootballPlayer`.

Context is defined from the codes point of view, if it expects a `BaseballPlayer`, it will only see a `BaseballPlayer`.

A `interface` simply defines a contract that a object guarantees to provide, so if it `implements` `BaseballPlayer`, it guarantees to implement all the functionality expected of the `BaseballPlayer` interface, equally can be said for `FootballPlayer`.

If the two classes have overlapping functionality (ie `getScore`), then you need to be able to manage it so that the `getScore` method knows the context in which it is been called (which is why I pass the `Sport` to it), otherwise your implementation has no hope of knowing what it should pass back - it lacks context